# Ordenar datos obtenidos con select multiple

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

Amigooooos

Requiero de su ayuda, tengo formulario con selección multiple, me arroja los datos que necesito, pero desordenados, como puedo ordenarlos... (Anexo imagen).

Esta es mi consulta:

```
$dia=$_GET['dias'];
//Mostramos las categorias seleccionadas
                echo "<br>Días seleccionados:";
                for ($i=0;$i<count($dia);$i++) 
                {
                echo "<br> Día " . $i . ": " . $dia[$i];
                }
// Tomamos el o los valores ingresados 
                $buscar_dia=implode ("','", $_GET['dias']);
//leo los datos de la base de datos
                $consulta02 = $conexion->query("SELECT dias, fechas, sum(carne_arabe) arabe FROM base WHERE dias IN('".$buscar_dia."') AND mes = 'JUNIO' AND anio = '2020' GROUP BY fechas ")or die("<br /> error en consulta: " .mysqli_error($conexion));
                echo '<table class="table">
                    <th>Días</th>
                    <th>Fechas</th>
                    <th>Carne Árabe</th>';
                while($ver = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta02)) {
                    echo '
                    <tr>
                    <td>'.$ver['dias'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$ver['fechas'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$ver['arabe'].'</td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>';
                }
```

Mi resultado es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría saber como puedo ordenar todo.

Actualización:
Gracias a @SJuan76 me funcionó el sacar el table del while, pero ahora estoy intentando ponerlo en forma lineal por medio de array, pero solo me muestra el primer día, como muestro en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es ¿Cómo puedo hacer que me lea el segundo día? y lo coloque como debe de ir. por ejemplo Lunes, Jueves

Comment: Confirmo ya quedó resuelto, solo añadi un nuevo foreach para el array dia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En estas cosas deberías mirar el HTML generado para ver porqué te sale así.

En concreto, tendrás algo así como:

```
<table class="table">
<th>Días</th>
<th>Fechas</th>
<th>Carne Árabe</th>
<tr><td>Martes</td><td>2021-01-06</td><td>0.25646</td></tr></table>
<tr><td>Miércoless</td><td>2021-01-07</td><td>0.25646</td></tr></table>
<tr><td>Jueves</td><td>2021-01-08</td><td>0.25646</td></tr></table>
....
```

Es decir, con cada iteración para mostrar una fila, estás añadiendo el tag `</table>` que concluye la tabla; las filas siguientes se muestran "fuera" de la tabla.

Saca el `</table>` del bucle y ponlo después de haber recorrido todos los elementos.

Comment: Ya puse el table fuera y si me respeta ya la posición de los datos, muchas gracias!.